# PyQt5: Add Variable Number of Rows to Layout Based on Python Dictionary

Tags: python, file, dictionary, layout, pyqt

Sorry if the question was a bit vague!
I am new to using PyQt (and making GUIs in general), and I am making a script that detects installed programs on my computer and retrieves the name of the program and its executable file path. So far I have a dictionary with file names as keys and the corresponding file paths as the key values.

Here is a snippet, though the actual dictionary is much longer:

```
{'Nexus Mod Manager': 'C:\\Games\\Nexus Mod Manager\\NexusClient.exe',
'CCleaner': 'E:\\Program Files\\CCleaner\\CCleaner.exe'}
```

My goal is to create a GUI that has a row for each key-value pair in the dictionary. I would also like to put 2 buttons (Yes and No) in each row to let the user choose if the file path is correct. If it is correct, it will execute some other function.

The problem is that the dictionary doesn't have one set length. On my computer, there are about 53 keys, but the number may be very different for another computer or if I install or uninstall programs in the future.

I prefer PyQt since that is the module in which I am most knowlegeable for creating GUIs, but I am open to other methods as well.

Thanks!

Comment: This boils down to how you can iterate a Python dictionary, which should be pretty easy to find information about on the web. Or is there something else? Maybe, if you have more specific questions, it would be useful to extract minimal example code for that.

Answer (score 0):

This can be implemented using Qt's model/view architecture.  [Heres a link to a tutorial from Qt](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/modelview.html), it's in c++, but it should be helpful.

Basically what you want to do is subclass QAbstractTableModel, then override the data method to display the info you need in each column based on your data structure (in this case a dictionary).

Below a second list of dictionary keys is used so that an index can be used in regards to which row is being populated.

```
    self.data_dict = {}
    self.row_display_list = [x for x in self.data_dict.keys()] # Assumes the dict is not empty

def data(self, index, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
    if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
        if index.column() == 0:
            return self.row_display_list[index.row()]
        elif index.column() == 1:
            return self.data_dict[self.row_display_list[index.row()]]
```

There are several different ways to implement this for different data structures.